# Prolificinteractive Material CalendarView: CurrentDay when set to a Monday, shows whole week from next month

Tags: android

For the calendar in my project, I am using **prolificinteractive material-calendarview**. When i set the week to start from Monday, it is showing the whole week from the next Month.

[image]

I have the following xml code:

```
 <com.prolificinteractive.materialcalendarview.MaterialCalendarView
        android:id="@+id/calendarView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:background="#03A9F4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:mcv_dateTextAppearance="@style/CalendarDateActivityStyle"
        app:mcv_headerTextAppearance="@style/CalendarHeaderActivityStyle"
        app:mcv_selectionColor="#000"
        app:mcv_showOtherDates="all"
        app:mcv_showWeekDays="true"
        app:mcv_tileHeight="45dp"
        app:mcv_weekDayTextAppearance="@style/CalendarWeekDayActivityStyle" />
```

and I am setting the start day of the week using the code snippet below:

```
calendarView.state().edit().setFirstDayOfWeek(DayOfWeek.MONDAY).commit();
```

I tried using **app:mcv_showOtherDates="out_of_range"** and that removes the dates from other months completely whereas i want to display partial dates from other months, e.g. the first row.

Any suggestions?

N.B. I am using the latest version of the library at present

```
 implementation 'com.github.prolificinteractive:material-calendarview:2.0.0'
```

Comment: Can I able to split the header and calendar in a separate background https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z16zO.png

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview/wiki/Customization#showing-other-dates

```
app:mcv_showOtherDates="none"
```

You should try this.

I have same problem.

But now its working just only this month.

This is result.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
calendarView.setDynamicHeightEnabled(true);
```